# SQL: how to use boolean logic within SELECT and WHERE statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, boolean-logic

I'm new to SQL.

I've got a complex SQL `SELECT` statement, simplified for this question. I am inheriting code and need to avoid altering it too much.

I need to add some functionality which selects extra columns only if a boolean value (`@myboolean`) is true:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]

--Parameters for the stored procedure
@myboolean as bit

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  
    field1 AS first_field,
    field2 AS second_field,

    /* PROBLEM 1: select field3 and field4 only if @myboolean is true */
    CASE 
        WHEN (@myboolean = 1) 
          THEN 
            field3 AS third_field,  
            field4 As fourth_field,
          ELSE
            /* do nothing, select nothing here */
    END,

    field5 AS fifth_field,
    field6 AS sixth_field


    WHERE  ( ( field1.value = thisvalue

    /* PROBLEM 2: add WHERE clause to check field2.status only if @myboolean is true
     * Currently only works if @myboolean = 1. I know this should be really simple but 
     * I can't figure it out.
     * Do I need to implement a CASE statement for when @myboolean = 0? See below */
    AND ((@myboolean = 1)  AND (field2.status = 2))

    AND field1.type IN ( 1, 2 ) )  
    AND (( field1.type NOT IN ( 28, 32 )  
    OR ( field1.type IS NULL ) )) )

END
```

So:

- when `@myboolean` is false, fields 1, 2, 5 and 6 should be selected - as in original code
- When `@myboolean` is true, fields 1-6 should be selected and `field2.status` should be checked

I've hunted around and all I can find is examples along the lines of `WHERE CASE @this THEN 1 ELSE 0`. I can't find out how to not check column values at all if boolean is false.

For Problem 2, I've also tried to implement a `CASE` statement, e.g.

```
    AND  field2.status  = 
         CASE
           WHEN (@myboolean = 1) 
           THEN 2 ELSE *
          END
```

Of course this gives a `syntax error near '*'` but I can't work out how it should be done.

**UPDATE:**
Just a reminder that the question is very simplified. The original SELECT statement is huge, and complex. There's actually several boolean values at play. I want to avoid wrapping the SELECT statements in `if`s as it will become a chaotic colossus of confused code very quickly.

**UPDATE:**
[Problem 2 solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876052/2294676) courtesy of @jpw (see edit to answer)

Comment: Is the complexity in the column list, or is that part relatively simple?

Comment: Yes - there are already several columns selected by the original statement, with lengthy CASE statements and various JOIN statements. I don't really want to alter existing code - I'd rather just add the necessary functionality if possible.

Comment: Regarding your "first problem", I would not make a stored procedure that returns tables with different structure (different number of columns) depending on its parameters. In RDBMS the schema is usually stable. If in certain cases the certain column is not needed, return `NULL` in it and ignore these columns in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

I've only just stumbled across this whilst looking for something else so apologies if this has long since been solved.

Here is an alternative way of looking at the problem\solution:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]

--Parameters for the stored procedure
@myboolean as bit

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  

    field1 AS first_field,
    field2 AS second_field,
    field3 AS third_field,  
    field4 As fourth_field,
    field5 AS fifth_field,
    field6 AS sixth_field
    WHERE ( ( field1.value = thisvalue
    AND ((@myboolean = 1)  AND (field2.status = 2))
    AND field1.type IN ( 1, 2 ) )  
    AND (( field1.type NOT IN ( 28, 32 )  
    OR ( field1.type IS NULL ) )) )

    UNION

    SELECT  

        field1 AS first_field,
        field2 AS second_field,
        NULL AS third_field,  
        NULL As fourth_field,
        field5 AS fifth_field,
        field6 AS sixth_field
        WHERE  ( ( field1.value = thisvalue
        AND ((@myboolean != 1)  AND (field2.status = 2))
        AND field1.type IN ( 1, 2 ) )  
        AND (( field1.type NOT IN ( 28, 32 )  
        OR ( field1.type IS NULL ) )) )

END
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this piece of code, it's a copy and paste job with a bit of tweaking but I hope it gives you a new direction in the form of using a UNION and returning the resultset based upon the setting of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first problem is that you can't dynamically choose what columns to output inside the query, but you have have to alter the logic "outside" the query using either control of flow statements (if-else) or dynamic sql (which would concatenate the final query string using parts selected depending on the variables used).

With a lot of variables this quickly can get out of hand as you noted, so the "best" solution might be to break down the large statement into several smaller parts and then glue them together as needed. Views might also be a tool to refactor the code into something less complex.

To answer the second part of your question, the condition that should work is:

`AND ((@myboolean = 1 AND field2.status = 2) OR @myboolean = 0)`

Comment: As commented on other answer - given the size and complexity of the SELECT statement, this would lead to an absolute nightmare to maintain. I'm really looking for embedded boolean logic.

Comment: @LydiaRalph If you want to choose what columns to include and don't want to duplicate the code then using dynamic SQL is probably the only viable approach. It will probably be a mess too though as the code would get chopped up and assembled from pieces.

Comment: Thanks will look into it

Comment: @LydiaRalph I added a bit that addresses the second problem you had.

Comment: brilliant thanks, your added bit worked for Problem 2. So this wouldn't work for Problem 1?

Comment: No, as you can't decide what columns to output conditionally without using either dynamic sql or the if-else logic used above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit out at the deep end here, as I've not used `CASE` before, but I've tried the following at [W3Schools sql editor](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), and it seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT CustomerId,
  CASE WHEN customerId < 5 -- Problem 1, first field
    THEN CustomerName
  END as optCustomerName,
  CASE WHEN customerId > 3 -- Problem 1, second field
    THEN ContactName
  END optContactName
FROM Customers
WHERE
  CustomerId < 15
  AND 
    CASE WHEN CustomerId < 5 -- Problem 2, a complete condition
       THEN CustomerName like 'an%'
       ELSE 1
    END;
```

Here are some comments regarding my code, and the corresponding changes you need to do to your code:

- In my example I've used the `customerId < 5` instead of `@myboolean = 0`
- It seems like a `CASE` statement is to replace one and only one column definition in the `SELECT` clause, as a consequence you need two `CASE`s to include both `field3` and `field4`
- I strongly suggest aliasing the `CASE` column definitions, as it looks ugly elsewise :-)
- As the number of fields from a `SELECT` should be constant, the default behaviour is to add `null` values when the conditions are not met. If this is not wanted, I do believe you need to use some variant of the `IF` statements suggested in another answer
- When using `CASE` instead of a where condition it looks nicer, and is easier to read if you enclose the entire part, and then providing a proper default when it doesn't match

With this knowledge I would suggest the following changes to your code:

```
...
field2 AS second_field,

CASE WHEN (@myboolean = 1) THEN field3
END as third_Field,

CASE WHEN (@myboolean = 1) THEN field4
END as fourth_Field,

field5 AS fifth_field,
...

WHERE  
  ...
  AND
    CASE 
       WHEN (@myboolean = 1) THEN field2.status = 2  
       ELSE 1 -- Always true, when not hitting the when @myboolean 
    END
  AND
  ...
```

Left out snippets here and there, especially in the `WHERE` clause, as it looked a little bit messy with all the parenthesis. But you should get the concept of how to make the change, hopefully.